# Android Talkback reads text visually positioned above input aloud

Tags: html, accessibility, talkback

I am trying to optimize a few components for screen readers, however Android Talkback proves to be a challenge....

Here is a very simplified example for the code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <form>
  <span role="presentation" aria-hidden="true">
   This should not be read by Talkback
  </span>

  <input aria-label="This should be read by Talkback" />
 </form>
</div>
```

The text inside the span is updated dynamically, and is positioned absolutely over the input - just to appear like an animated placeholder, without actually being read by screen readers. That is what the aria-label is for. However, TalkBack still seems to recognize the span - so it reads the content of the aria-label first, then continues reading the text in the span... role "presentation" or role "none" did not prevent this, neither did moving the text even further from the input. (For example, outside the form). Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `role` attribute only changes the **type** of element that Talkback and other screen readers announce.  Setting it to `presentation` or `none` just removes the semantic type of element.  A `<span>` does not have a native role by default so it's essentially presentation/none implicitly and won't have any effect.

[`aria-hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-hidden) is the key.  It will hide the element from the screen reader.  (CSS `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` will also hide an element from the screen reader but it also makes the element invisible to sighted users too.)

Your code example should work just fine with Talkback.  However, you mentioned that you dynamically change the contents of the `<span>`.  That's not a problem but is there a chance that when you updated the text, the `aria-hidden` got removed?

I have used `aria-hidden` on Android without any trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But that is the thing - i had aria-hidden in place for a while, but it does not fix the issue. I also made sure that aria-hidden does not get removed when the element is updated.

Weirdly, only hiding the element visually or moving it to not overlap with the input field seems to fix the issue. But that is not really an option since we would be losing a feature intended for sighted users.

Comment: I don't have an android device to test this but in the past, `aria-hidden` has worked just fine.  Can you try a simple example on android and see if hidden is being honored?  `<span>hello</span> <span aria-hidden="true">there</span> <span>world</span>`  Swipe to navigate and see if you get to all 3 elements or just the "hello" and "world".

Comment: `aria-hidden` is respected insofar as that the element is not focusable. (So it works as you said). But my issue is a different one - while the focus moves correctly and does -not- move to the span, the issue is with what the screen reader announces while the input is focused. It will start reading the aria-label of the input, then continue reading the text inside the span, as if it was an actual text located inside the input. And the only thing that seems to trigger this is the fact that the span is "visually" positioned directly on (as in, overlapping with) the input.

Comment: Okay, weirdly enough I seem to have fixed the issue. Actually, the order of dom elements in my current code was different than in my example here - the span actually came after the input. Moving the span before the input, like in my example, seems to have fixed the issue completely. `aria-hidden` was present in both cases though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my example was already enough to fix the issue.
aria-hidden prevents the span being focusable, and if the span is located before (and not after), TalkBack will not interpret the text as being part of the input.